# Error while saving as parquet {Could not read footer}

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

I am writing a spark application. 
After processing logs , i save the output in parquet format. (using Dataframe.saveAsParquetFile() api)
But I am getting error sometime while saving as parquet. The error goes away if i rerun the process to save as parquet.

Please let me know root cause for this

```
java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus@6233d82f
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache.refresh(newParquet.scala:369)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2.org$apache$spark$sql$parquet$ParquetRelation2$$metadataCache$lzycompute(newParquet.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2.org$apache$spark$sql$parquet$ParquetRelation2$$metadataCache(newParquet.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2.refresh(newParquet.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.insert(commands.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(commands.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile(DataFrame.scala:1494)
        at ParquetWriter$.main(ParquetWriter.scala:182)
        at ParquetWriter.main(ParquetWriter.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus@6233d82f
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:230)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/{directory}/output.parquet2/part-r-01418.gz.parquet at 17920
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.fill(FSInputChecker.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.seek(FSInputChecker.java:412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FSDataBoundedInputStream.seek(ChecksumFileSystem.java:318)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:413)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:228)
        ... 5 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Scala, Java, Python or R? show the code where you attempt to save it, print and show us the schema, and show us a sample of the DF